# How to count "/" in words, extracting tags (like </s>)

Tags: xml, count, notepad++

Input in Notepad++:
`<s>asmE/, asyE/, asmA/t, asyA/s, asya/, asmi/n, asyA/m, AByA/m, eBi/s, ABi/s, eBya/s, ABya/s, ezA/m, AsA/m, ezu/, Asu/</s>` at http://regex101.com/r/yM2fA1/1

`/` is used for marking accent in a XML document I work with from http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/PWGScan/2013/downloads/pwgxml.zip. But if I'll count only `/`, I will get `</s></hom></h>` etc. junk counted as well. How to exclude the XML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(?<!<)/(?! ?>)`

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!<)  : lookbehind, there're no < before the slash
/       : slash character to be searched
(?! ?>) : lookahead, there're no > (eventualy preceded by a space) after the slash
```

Here is the doc on [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Pure magic, it works like a charm and just in seconds. Lookaheadbehind lesson is yet to be learnt by me. It's robust and no dirt, great.

Answer (score 0):

For counting purpose only:

Ctrl+F or click *Find* from the *Search* dropdown menu and type  `/` as the thing to be searched. Now click on *Find all in Current Document* . That should give you the number of `/` you have in the document. Take a note of the number.

Now repeat the process but now search for `</` . The difference of the count is the actual count for your desired search.

Comment: Bad idea. In my 56 Mb document just counting '/' takes around 20 minutes with my 4 RAM, a few million cases. And I have four documents that regularly get updated. So I want to have it in one go in EmEditor or Notepad++, or PHP with some RegEx magic. Without my calculator.

Comment: You can search in multiple documents with Notepad++ . You slow search is unfortunate. Try copy pasting the text and searching with a different tool like ms word or google chrome or firefox etc. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful